# angular-cache doesn't clear local storage cache when using DSCacheFactory.destroyAll or clearAll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, angular-cache

I'm using angular-cache for the localStorage functionality. However, I have found that when trying to destroy or empty all of my caches, only the in memory cache seems to be cleared, not the localStorage cache. How can I make it so both caches are cleared?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug report. In the meantime, I've implemented this code immediately after a call to DSCacheFactory.destroyAll():

```
for(var i in $window.localStorage){
    if(i.indexOf("angular-cache.caches")>-1){
      $window.localStorage.removeItem(i);
    }
}
```